# Generate 3D curve from two 2D plane curve

Tags: python, 3d, 2d, curve, plane

I have two lists that are actually two planar curves. For example:

```
XY = [[1.0,0.0],[1.0,0.5],[0.0,1.0]]
YZ = [[0.0,1.0],[1.0,0.0]]
```

And the goal is to create a 3D list of points out of this two curves. In this case, the result curve would look like this:
[image]
And the result list would look like something like this:

```
XYZ = [[1.0,0.0,1.0],[1.0,0.5,0.5],[0.0,1.0,0.0]]
```

I had the idea to generate a surface and then compute the intersection between but not sure it is the most elegant and simple way to do it. Here is the simple code I am using for now:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
from scipy.interpolate import interp1d


nPoints = 100

XY = [[1.0,0.0],[1.0,0.5],[0.0,1.0]]
YZ = [[0.0,1.0],[1.0,0.0]]


XY = list(map(list, zip(*XY)))
YZ = list(map(list, zip(*YZ)))

XY_interp = interp1d(XY[1],XY[0],fill_value='extrapolate')
YZ_interp = interp1d(YZ[0],YZ[1],fill_value='extrapolate')

yRange = np.linspace(min(XY[1]),max(XY[1]),nPoints)

LE = [[XY_interp(y),y,YZ_interp(y)] for y in yRange]
LE = list(map(list, zip(*LE)))



figsize = [20,10]



x = np.linspace(0,0,len(YZ))
ax = plt.figure(figsize=figsize).gca(projection='3d')

ax.plot(XY[0],XY[1],c='blue',label='XY plane curve')
ax.plot(x,YZ[0],YZ[1],c='red',label='YZ plane curve')
ax.plot(LE[0],LE[1],LE[2],c='black',label='3D result curve')
ax.legend()
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

Thank you very much

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you are trying to do. What exactly have you tried already?

Comment: Hi, sorry it wasnt clear. I updated my post with a figure so you can visualise what I want to do. Thank you

Comment: That... doesn't look like a curve? that's three different 3d polygons.

Comment: Call it as you want. For me it is a one degree curve or line. It is a very simple case but I actually generate this two lists from a bezier curve. I just simplified here for the example.